# How do I generalize this function using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function (below) that, when the DOM loads it finds every select input and adds an attribute `data-prev` that keeps track of what the *previous* selected value was in the event the value is changed.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  //For each select field, add a data-prev attribute set for tracking the previous value for when it gets changed
  $('select').each(function(){
    $(this).attr("data-prev", $(this).val())
  });
}
```

Now, my page includes select fields that get created dynamically (after the page loads) for which I also need to set the `data-prev` attribute. So, I was thinking it would make sense for me to generalize the function above into something like

```
function SetDataPrevAttr(element=None)
    if element is None:
        for each select field in DOM set the attribute data-prev to its current value
    else:
        for each select field in the descendant elements of element (including element) set the attribute data-prev to its current value
```

How would I do this?

Comment: How will that function know when to run on the dynamic inputs?

Comment: In the same block of code used to create the select field(s), I'd do something like `call SetDataPrevAttr(myNewForm)`, or at least that's my idea.

Comment: I'm not 100% what you are aiming for but you could you just make it simpler and using something like `$(document).on('change', 'select', function() {` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function SetDataPrevAttr(elem) {
    elem.each(function () {
        $(this).attr('data-prev', $(this).val());
    });
}

$(function() {
    SetDataPrevAttr($('select'));
});
```

Then on adding each new element you could do the following:

```
var element = $('<select></select>').appendTo(document);
SetDataPrevAttr(element);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just set the previous value when the `<select>` gets focus (ie, before it changes)? That way, you can just use a delegate event handler. For example...

```
$(document).on('focus', 'select', function() {
    var $sel = $(this);
    if (!$sel.data('prev')) {
        $sel.data('prev', $sel.val());                  
    }
});
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j0ge8Lf6/1/)</kbd>

Comment: This is a better approach than what I was planning on doing.